# check if two numeric values have same sign in numpy (+/-)

Tags: python, numpy

currently i am using numpy.logical_or with numpy.logical_and to check if elements of two arrays have same sign. Was wondering if there is already a ufunc  or a more effective method that will achieve this. My current solutions is here

```
a = np.array([1,-2,5,7,-11,9])
b = np.array([3,-8,4,81,5,16])
out = np.logical_or(
                    np.logical_and((a < 0),(b < 0)), 
                    np.logical_and((a > 0),(b > 0))
                                             )
```

edit//
output

```
out
Out[51]: array([ True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: What about zero? Zero and zero have the same sign but you don't recognize it.

Comment: Don't forget that floats have a signed zero.

Comment: Yup! from the answers here i realize that i have to be careful using zero. Anyways, my current solution was not effective, hence the question. Thanks, SO is amazing.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

One approach with elementwise product and then check for `>=0`, as same signs (both positive or both negative) would result in positive product values -

```
((a== b) & (a==0)) | (a*b>0)
```

Another with explicit sign check -

```
np.sign(a) == np.sign(b)
```

Runtime test -

```
In [155]: a = np.random.randint(-10,10,(1000000))

In [156]: b = np.random.randint(-10,10,(1000000))

In [157]: np.allclose(np.sign(a) == np.sign(b), ((a== b) & (a==0)) | (a*b>0))
Out[157]: True

In [158]: %timeit np.sign(a) == np.sign(b)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.06 ms per loop

In [159]: %timeit ((a== b) & (a==0)) | (a*b>0)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.54 ms per loop

# @salehinejad's soln
In [160]: %timeit np.where((np.sign(a)+np.sign(b))==0)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.71 ms per loop
```

Comment: `a*b >= 0` fails for example for `a, b = np.array([0]), np.array([-1])`.

Comment: I was arriving at a similar contradicting case as well. A mathematician would never claim that `0` is positive. Nevertheless, I think that `a*b>0` condition is perfectly fine

Answer (score 4):

In vanilla Python you could do something like:

```
abs(a + b) == abs(a) + abs(b)
```

That will return true if the signs are equal.

Comment: Too complex. `a * b > 0` is simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Addition is cheaper than multiplication. For non-equal signs:

```
np.where((np.sign(a)+np.sign(b))!=0)
```

For equal signs:

```
np.where((np.sign(a)+np.sign(b))==0)
```

This approach returns the indices; Not just True/False etc.

Output for the given a and b in question:

[0 1 2 3 5]

May try np.sum() for more than two variables.

Comment: Huh, I'm pretty sure that only tells you if the signs are *opposite and equal*, no?

Comment: np.sign() return -1 or +1. So it ignores the values.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.randn(5)
b = np.random.randn(5)

print a
print b

# Method 1
print np.logical_not(np.sign(a*b)-1)

# Method 2 ***probably best
print np.equal(np.sign(a), np.sign(b))

# Method 3
print np.where((a*b<0),np.zeros(5,dtype=bool),np.ones(5,dtype=bool))

# Method 4
print np.core.defchararray.startswith(np.array(-a*b).astype('str'),'-')

>>>
[-0.77184408 -0.55291345 -0.45774947  0.67080435 -0.286555  ]
[ 0.37220055  0.29489477 -1.05773195  1.03833121  1.01538001]
[False False True True False]
[False False True True False]
[False False True True False]
[False False True True False]
```

Method 1

- a*b produces array of values, negative when signs are different
- np.sign() converts array to -1 and 1
- subtracting 1 converts array to -2 and 0
- np.logical_not() converts -2 to False; and 0 to True

Method 2

- np.sign() converts to -1, 1
- np.equal() compares two arrays and gives truth value if equal element wise

Method 3

- np.where(condition[, x, y])Return elements, either from x or y, depending on condition.
- np.zeros(5,dtype=bool),np.ones(5,dtype=bool) are arrays of False and True respectively

Method 4

- multiply -a*b
- convert resultant array to dtype string
- check which elements start with a -

reference:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.logic.html

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.core.defchararray.startswith.html#numpy.core.defchararray.startswith

Comment: up vote for np.equal based solution, it is most intuitive with only one step solution (compared to addition,multiplication, etc elsewhere). But @Divakar was first to highlight it, so will accept his solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can rely on bitwise operator XOR

`x ^ y`

the XOR operation is applied to the sign as well, so when they're the same the result is greater than 0 and if not it's less than 0

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why no one went for the actual mathematical operation:

`a * b < 0`

In case you need the formula without numpy arrays

Comment: It should be greater than 0 to check for same sign. [The accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43380854/13138364) already uses this, and it also catches the case when `a` and `b` are zero: `((a==b) & (a==0)) | (a*b>0)`